# Taking input from user with switch case and while loop

Tags: java, user-interface, while-loop, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a program that asks input from an user:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MainEJP6_NodesTrees {
    static Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    static long numAccounts = 100_000L;
    static String op;
    
    private static void startmenu() {
        boolean b = false;
        while(!b) {
            System.out.println("Start Menu\n"
                    + "1 - List EJP-6 Linked_Nodes_Trees\n"
                    + "2 - exit program");
            op = sc.next();
            switch(op) {
            case "1":
                b = true;
                algoMenu();
                break;
            case "2":
                exit();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please type valid input");  
                
            }
                
        }
        
    
    }

    private static void algoMenu() {
        boolean b = false;
        String op;
        while(!b) {
            System.out.println("Algorithms Menu\n"
                    + "1 - Generate Members\n"
                    + "2 - Backto StartMenu\n"
                    + "3 - Exit program");
            op = sc.next();
            switch(op) {
            case "1":
                b = true;
                algoGenerator();
                break;
            case "2":
                b = true;
                startmenu();
                break;
            case "3":
                exit();
                break;
            default:
                    System.out.println("Please enter valid response");
            }
        
        }
    }

    private static void algoGenerator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean b = false;
        while(!b) {
            System.out.println("Algorithms Menu\n"
                    + "1 - Generate x AccountsList\n"
                    + "2 - Generate x AccountsTree\n"
                    + "3 - Generate x AccountsHeap\n"
                    + "4 - Back to Algorithms menu\n"
                    + "5 - Exit program\n");
            System.out.println("Enter response below:");
            op = sc.next();
            switch(op) {
            case "1":
                b = true;
                break;
            case "2":
                b = true;
                break;
            case "3":
                b = true;
                break;
            case "4":
                b = true;
                algoMenu();
                break;
            case "5":
                exit();
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter valid response.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args ) {
        startmenu();
    }

    private static void exit() {
        boolean b = false;
        while(!b) {
            System.out.println("Are you sure you want to exit program?\n"
                    + "1 - Yes\n"
                    + "0 - No");
            op = sc.next();
            switch(op) {
            case "1":
                b = true;
                System.out.println("Exiting");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case "0":
                b = true;
                startmenu();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter valid input");
                
                    
            }   
        }
        
    }
}
```

I thought it worked fine but after running it a few times and going back to the main menu and starting over I realized at one point it would send me to the main menu instead of running what's next (which for now it's blank because I haven't finished it and I wanted to get rid of any errors before proceeding).

the compiler:

```
Start Menu
1 - List EJP-6 Linked_Nodes_Trees
2 - exit program
2
Are you sure you want to exit program?
1 - Yes
0 - No
0
Start Menu
1 - List EJP-6 Linked_Nodes_Trees
2 - exit program
1
Algorithms Menu
1 - Generate Members
2 - Backto StartMenu
3 - Exit program
2
Start Menu
1 - List EJP-6 Linked_Nodes_Trees
2 - exit program
1
Algorithms Menu
1 - Generate Members
2 - Backto StartMenu
3 - Exit program
1
**Algorithms Menu
1 - Generate x AccountsList
2 - Generate x AccountsTree
3 - Generate x AccountsHeap
4 - Back to Algorithms menu
5 - Exit program
Enter response below:
1
Start Menu
1 - List EJP-6 Linked_Nodes_Trees
2 - exit program**
```

As you see when i type "1" to generate x AccountsLists it instead sends me to the start menu.

Comment: "... I realized at one point it would..." What are the exact steps that causes it to send you to the main menu? The first step in fixing a bug is to reproduce it in as few steps as possible. After you figure that out, check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips for what to do next.

Comment: At the end when I type 1 to generate accountslists it sends me to the start menu again. I forgot to add that comment

Comment: I see now. The end of your question shows the input and output while you run the program. Can you cause the problem in fewer steps? If not, then it's time to start debugging to figure out what is going on.

Comment: I did it and i realized it happens every time after i run the exit() and choose not exiting.

Comment: Ok, now add some `System.out.println()` to try and figure out why that happens. Or use a visual debugger. I linked an article in my first comment with more tips.

Comment: I added two sysout() lines in case 1 and case 2 in startmenu() and it goes back to those lines when the error occurs.

Comment: That's a good start. Continue adding more until you track down the problem.